# Can't get to the root on juniper ssg5

Tags: networking, backup, root, firewall, juniper-network-connect

Can't get to the root on juniper ssg5

After i enter my login username and password I'm stuck on this prompt

```
'my-fw->'


my-fw-> copy
 ^------unknown keyword copy
my-fw-> show
 ^------unknown keyword show
my-fw-> configure
^-----------unknown keyword configure
```

why can't i get to `root@my-fw->` or `root@my-fw-#`  prompt. What can i do to get to root. I'm using putty to console to the juniper ssg5.

[Note- I'm trying to backup config to a tftp server where i require to get to the root access]

Comment: [Looking at the docs](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/screenos/screenos6.3.0/630_ipv4_cli.pdf), non of these are valid keywords?

Comment: I'm logged in as an admin user with root privilege and it's giving me only my company name e.g, mycompany-myfw->

But the task i want to perform is 'Auto backup my config to a tftp server' not just saving a single copy or downloading a single copy. Here's two link i was following for that-

http://www.junosworkbook.com/workbooks/jncia/backing-up-and-restoring-junos-configuration

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/junos-cookbook/0596100140/ch01s15.html

Is it possible to achieve the task at all with those two link or is there any other way to achieve it. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root access. root is an special account and all / most of the commands works without root account. Any account which has privileges to perform configuration changes, can apply the command to archive the configuration on given site. 
See [junos-os-login-classes-overview](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/junos-os-login-class.html#id-junos-os-login-classes-overview) for user privileges.

The prompt we get is in this format: user@hostname> [Ref](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16580&actp=METADATA)

If there is no hostname defined, then it is just: user> 
Once you make sure that you have logged in with correct user, i.e. it has requirement permissions, you should be able to execute those commands and apply [archival](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/junos-software-system-management-router-configuration-archiving.html) configuration.

I have a working solution, let me know if above doesn't help.